# Create vector of size elements, without calling copy constructor?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a way to create a vector of N elements **without** calling the copy constructor and instead calling the elements' default constructor? I do not want a copy constructor for the elements because copying should be prevented.

Here it looks like you can, option 3:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

> 3) Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of
>   T. **No copies are made**.

but here it looks like you cannot:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

> 1. empty container constructor (default constructor) Constructs an empty container, with no elements.
> 2. fill constructor Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of val (if provided).
> 3. range constructor Constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element emplace-constructed from its
>      corresponding element in that range, in the same order.
> 4. copy constructor (and copying with allocator) Constructs a container with a copy of each of the elements in x, in the same order.
> 5. move constructor (and moving with allocator) Constructs a container that acquires the elements of x. If alloc is specified and
>      is different from x's allocator, the elements are moved. Otherwise, no
>      elements are constructed (their ownership is directly transferred). x
>      is left in an unspecified but valid state.
> 6. initializer list constructor Constructs a container with a copy of each of the elements in il, in the same order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is how vector works.

You misread the cplusplus.com wording. It says "fill constructor Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of `val` (if provided)"; you can't get away from that. But you *don't* provide `val`!

We can trivially demonstrate with the following simple code that copies are not (or, at least, do not need to be) made when the elements are default-constructed:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    T() { std::cout << "def-cons\n"; }
    ~T() { std::cout << "dest\n"; }
    T(const T&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> v(5);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cd1270335073505))

The standard itself is clear that the elements need only be default-constructible, no copyability required:

> `[C++11: 23.3.6.2]:` `explicit vector(size_type n);`
>
> 3. Effects: Constructs a `vector` with `n` value-initialized elements.
> 4. Requires: **`T` shall be `DefaultConstructible`.**
> 5. Complexity: Linear in `n`.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the version of C++ you're using.  Before C++11, the only
way to get an element into a vector was by copying:

```
std::vector<T> v( 10 );
```

was the equivalent of:

```
std::vector<T> v( 10, T() );
```

with the default constructed `T` copied 10 times.  C++11 changed this,
and the first form is required to default construct `T` 10 times,
without any copying.